# How to apply CSS rules after a certain tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title states, I have the following HTML which looks as the following:

```
<div id="content">
  <main>
    <h2 > Example Title</h2>
    <p>Hello World</p>

    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md btn-table">
      <tr>
        <td>Example 1 </td>
        <td>Example 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>    
  </main>
</div>
```

After the `<h2>` example title I would like to apply the CSS rule: `margin-top:20px;`, `margin-bottom:20px`, to all the other tags which are `<p>`, `<table>`.

How do I do it?

Comment: What about `tr` and `td`? Those come after `h2` also...

Comment: Something like the [General Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator), e.g.: `h2 ~ p, h2 ~ table`?

Comment: Thank you! works really great especially in combination wih the @HereticMonkey Contribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways of going about this without changing the HTML.

The first way is to say, "Get me all of the children of `main` that are not the `h2`.

The other way, inspired by [a comment by chriskirknielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61351818/how-to-apply-css-rules-after-a-certain-tag#comment108534634_61351818), is to use the General Sibling Combinator and get all of the siblings of the `h2`.

Of course, both of these assume that it is "all elements at the same level" that you want and not "all elements at the same level after a specific point in the DOM" because the latter is simply not possible.

```css
main > *:not(h2) {
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

/* OR */

h2 ~ * {
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <main>
    <h2 > Example Title</h2>
    <p>Hello World</p>

    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md btn-table">
      <tr>
        <td>Example 1 </td>
        <td>Example 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>    
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class and add it to all the elements after the h2. For example:

```
.example{
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-botton:20px;
}
```

OR

you can give the margin-top: 20px and margin-botton:20px to all the elements and exclude the h2 by giving it an id. For example:

```
#example{
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has also the Javascript tag, here it is a Javascript solution.

Let's see again your HTML. `onload` we call the `applyStyleChanges()` function:

```html
  <body onload="applyStyleChanges()">
    <div id="content">
      <main>
        <p>Unaffected</p>
        <!-- ... -->
        <h2 > Example Title</h2>
        <p>Hello World</p>

        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md btn-table">
          <tr>
            <td>Example 1 </td>
            <td>Example 2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Function `applyStyleChanges()` can be defined as shown below:

```
<script>
  function applyStyleChanges()
  {
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0];

    while(node = node.nextSibling)
    {
      if(node.nodeType == 1)
      {
        node.style.marginTop    = "20px";
        node.style.marginBottom = "20px";
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

### Explanation

1. We get our *"boundary"* element. In this case it is the first `h2`
2. We loop on `node.nextSibling` until the end of the sibling list is reached
3. For every sibling we choose only those of type "1" ([element nodes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp))
4. For every chosen element we apply the desired set of `node.style` assignments
5. All the siblings before our *"boundary"* element are unaffected
6. Please note how `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` properties are accessed through `marginTop` and `marginBottom` respectively. In JS properties dash are removed and a *camel case* notation is used

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! I did choose the approach above but its great to know different ways of doing things!

Answer (score -1):

You can just

```
p{
margin-top: 20px;
margin-botton:20px;
}
```

OR

you can give class names to the tags for ex:- `<p class='someClass'>` and in the css select that particular tag by

```
.someClass{
margin-top: 20px;
margin-botton:20px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `:not()` selector

```
main:not(h2) {marginstuff}
```

it will exclude h2 but be applied to everything else in main

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not